# Camera on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: camera, pi-zero

Is it possible to connect the pins of the Raspberry Pi camera to the GPIO of the Raspberry Pi Zero (as it does not have a port for the camera)?

Is it a good idea? I want to do this because I want to move the load of a convolutional network processing from Raspberry Pi 2 B+ to a dedicated Raspberry Pi Zero which, in turn, will have several GPIO connected with the B+ board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no way to connect the camera board's CSI output to the GPIO pins that will leave you with a functional camera.

Comment: The revised board of the Pi Zero provides the camera connector (*The Gift* of the Pi Foundation), see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/zero-grows-camera-connector/).

Answer (score 3):

http://raspi.tv/2016/raspberry-pi-zero-1-3-with-camera-port

New version allows adding cam.

Comment: Link only answers are not ideal, could you please add some detail to your answer.